# Replace text from generated RSS feeds

Tags: php, string, replace, rss, str-replace

Here is the page with the problem, http://knowgreaterpartnership.com/secrets/.

The RSS generator that we use is inserting inline html tags on the "events" feed such as `<br>`, `<i>` and `</i>`.

Here is the code I've ended up with to try and remove these bits from my code:

```
<div id="right" class="last">

    <h1><?php esc_html_e( 'Buchanan Events', 'Fusion' ); ?></h1>
    <article id="jobs">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'fetch_feed' ) ) { ?>
            <?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
                $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://www.bipc.com/rssfeeds/rss.aspx?id=35' );
                $feednew = str_replace( array( '<br>', '<i>', '</i>' ), '', $feed );
                $limit = $feednew -> get_item_quantity(5);
                $items = $feednew -> get_items(0, $limit);
            if ( !$items ) {
                echo "problem";
            }
            else {
                //everything's cool
                foreach( $items as $item ){ ?>

                    <h2 class="post"><a class="link" href="<?php echo $item -> get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item -> get_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="date"><?php echo $item -> get_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?></p>
                    <hr>

                <?php }
            } ?>
        <?php } ?>

    </article>

</div>
```

---

I'm trying to use **str_replace()** to search for the `<br>`, `<i>` and `</i>` tags and replace them with nothing so that the rest of the text flows.

If I'm not using the right method, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get rid of all html tags just use strip_tags()

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and it will remove all html/php tags (html comments included).

```
$feed = strip_tags($feed);
```

Comment: So this is what I've amended:

`<?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');  
     $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://www.bipc.com/rssfeeds/rss.aspx?id=35' );
     $feed = strip_tags( '$feed' );
     $limit = $feed -> get_item_quantity(5);
     $items = $feed -> get_items(0, $limit);`

Unfortunately this broke the feed and won't load anything.

Comment: @JeffSydor That's the way you get rid off html tags. What do you mean with "broke" ? errors?

Comment: @JeffSydor What is the output of: `var_dump($feed);` before and after the `strip_tags()` call?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what that means.

Comment: I added that after the `$feed = strip_tags( $feed );` and all I got was this: `string(32) "4ca2a7bfd4cc1fed6a9478ba78a2f610"`

Comment: @JeffSydor But your code works if you don't use `strip_tags()` ?

Comment: @JeffSydor And what is the output of `var_dump($feed);` if you don't use `strip_tags()` ?

Comment: A ton of code, check back on the site for it. It looks like a very stripped down version of the feed.

Comment: @JeffSydor Now we found it! The `fetch_feed()` doesn't return a string with text and html tags in it! It's a `SimplePie` object! So I would recommend you to look into your plugin which you use (since `fetch_feed()` isn't a php function) if there is an option to get rid of html tags, otherwise it will become almost impossible and pain to get rid of the html tags. (So I wouldn't be able to help you there! But one l have one last idea: Try to use `strip_tags()` when you are output stuff from your feed!)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. It's not a plug-in that is generating the RSS feeds. It is our company's website manager (not wordpress or any of the other common platforms) that produces them.